# Reading Data in Pandas from Excel File separated with different segments

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, split

I have an excel file which looks like this :

[image]

I want to read the file into multiple data frames based on the flags like here :

DataEx1, DataEx2 and DataEx3.

So my output should like the following

```
  df1 

      A1    A2  A3  A4  A5
      1     a   u   4   10
      2     b   u   5   12

   df2 

       B1   B2  B3
       x    1   
       y    2   3
       z    12  0

 df3 

     C1 C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
     10 12  15  20  10  s
     20 1   45  2   4   t
     30 7   23  20  4   u
     4  8   12  2   4   v
```

I have tried using pd.read_excel with skiprows functionality. However, not able to get how to use the indicators to read the different data labels separately and load into three different data frames?

Not able to figure the best pythonic way. Any help will immensely appreciated.

Comment: Is DataEx something always there before the data? And does the data always exist in col A or can it start in any column?

Comment: Thank you @Jason Baker. Yes DatEx Pattern always is there and its starts at Col A .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the location of tables are fixed, it's easy to load into df.

```py
import pandas as pd
excel_file_path = r'd:/temp/table.xlsx'  
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0, usecols='A:C', skiprows=4, nrows=3)
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0, usecols='A:D', skiprows=9, nrows=6)
print("DataFrame 1:")
print(df1)
print("\nDataFrame 2:")
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
DataFrame 1:                           
    A   B   C                          
0  11  11  11                          
1  11  11  11                          
                                       
DataFrame 2:                           
   AA  BB  CC  DD                      
0  22  22  22  22                      
1  22  22  22  22                      
2  22  22  22  22                      
3  22  22  22  22                      
4  22  22  22  22
```

[image]

---

> Question: Is it not possible to use the identifiers ( like DataEx01/02 etc) to create the dataframes from there? That pattern is fixed that every time the data starts just from the next row from DataEx1 or dataEx2 etc.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
excel_file_path = r'd:/temp/table.xlsx'  # Update as needed
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None)
# print("All data on sheet1:")
# print(df)
df_col = df.columns
sub_dfs = []
split_mode = False
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] is not np.nan and str(row[0]).startswith('DataEx'):
        if split_mode:
            current_df = pd.concat([current_df, pd.DataFrame([row])], ignore_index=True)
        else:
            current_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_col)
            split_mode = True
    elif split_mode:
        if row[0] is np.nan:
            split_mode = False
            current_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
            current_df.columns = current_df.iloc[0]
            sub_dfs.append(current_df[1:].reset_index(drop=True))
        else:
            current_df = pd.concat([current_df, pd.DataFrame([row])], ignore_index=True)
    else:
        pass
current_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
current_df.columns = current_df.iloc[0]
sub_dfs.append(current_df[1:].reset_index(drop=True))
for i, sub_df in enumerate(sub_dfs):
    print(f'DataFrame {i + 1}:')
    print(sub_df)
    print(sub_df.columns)
    print('-' * 10)
```

**Output**

```
DataFrame 1:                                                                                  
0   A   B   C                                                                                 
0  11  11  11                                                                                 
1  11  11  11                                                                                 
Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name=0)                                                
----------                                                                                    
DataFrame 2:                                                                                  
0  AA  BB  CC  DD                                                                             
0  22  22  22  22                                                                             
1  22  22  22  22                                                                             
2  22  22  22  22                                                                             
3  22  22  22  22                                                                             
4  22  22  22  22                                                                             
Index(['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'], dtype='object', name=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @taller_ExcelHome. My bad, I should have pointed out. Usually the location in general may change, depending on how I get the data. (as each of them of can have different nrows each time) I understand then the solution will be difficult to achieve?

Comment: Is it not possible to use the identifiers ( like DataEx01/02 etc) to create the dataframes from there? That pattern is fixed that every time the data starts just from the next row from DataEx1 or dataEx2 etc.

Comment: I think it is a good start point. The extra step is reading Excel file with openpyxl to location the table.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have some example of how to do that?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will implement and let you know.